# C# DateTime down to the minute from linq

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I'am trying to compare two `DateTimes` down the the minute from a `DateTime.Now` and a SQL entry. I see the problem being that the ticks are slightly off due to the kind being returned from the DB. However I can't figure out a work around.

This is my `DateTime` to grab

```
DateTime toGrab = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10)
                              .AddSeconds(-DateTime.Now.Second)     
                              .AddMilliseconds(-DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
```

And there is my linq expression.

```
cc.DBAppointments.Where(c => c.StartDate == toGrab && c.Approved == 1).ToList();
```

Any advise?

Comment: You are calling `DateTime.Now` multiple times, this might give you different results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are using `Entity Framework` for this.
If you just need to compare the datetime up until minutes, you can use `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions` to access canonical functions in linq-to-entities.
You can use this for example:

```
cc.DBAppointments
  .Where(c => DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(c.StartDate,DateTime.Now) == 0 && c.Approved == 1)
  .ToList();
```

This way you have access to advanced sql datetime comparison and you don't have to do tricks adding seconds/milliseconds to your `DateTime.Now`. This function will **ignore everything smaller than minutes** .

Comment: This is even more pure than meets the eye, because EF translates `DateTime.Now` into t-SQL's function `SysDateTime()`, so the comparison matches exactly with the time the database executes the query. Theoretically, a `DateTime` variable from a client could be seconds off when it finally gets evaluated. Not to mention (not so theoretical) differences between client and server clocks.

Comment: That was the trick i always forget about the dbfunctions, just a small correcting the resource is System.Data.Entity.

Answer (score 4):

You're making multiple references to `DateTime.Now`, which possibly has a different value each time. The following should work better:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var toGrab = now.Date.AddHours(now.Hour).AddMinutes(now.Minute + 10);
```

Note that, in order to get a clear "top of the minute", adding hours and minutes to a date would work better than trying to remove the seconds and milliseconds because there's more detail in a `DateTime` than milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
DateTime toGrab = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10)
                              .AddSeconds(-DateTime.Now.Second)
                              .AddMilliseconds(-DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
```

To

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime toGrab = now.AddMinutes(10)
                     .AddSeconds(-now.Second)
                     .AddMilliseconds(-now.Millisecond);
```

On a different note, is there any reason why you would need to grab an appointment to the exact millisecond?  It seems very prone to missing records?

**Edit**

Also, in your database, the value `2015-12-10 10:33:48.373` is different to `2015-12-10 10:33:48.374` even though they are 1 milisecond apart.  If you want to get a broader range, you can do `c.StartDate >= startDate && c.StartDate <= endDate && c.Approved == 1`

Comment: Note that this still wouldn't give you a clear "top of the minute", since there's more detail in `DateTime` than a millisecond.

Answer (score 1):

You can do [comparisons on TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan_operators(v=vs.110).aspx) objects, which means you can do it like this:

```
TimeSpan oneMinute = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
cc.DBAppointments.Where(c =>
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10).Subtract(c.StartDate) < oneMinute &&
    c.Approved == 1).ToList();
```

Of course if `c.StartDate` is *less than 9* minutes in the future, the subtraction will have a result of <-1 minutes.  I'm not sure if your objective is *within 1 minute*.  If that's the case, you can add [`.Duration()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.duration(v=vs.110).aspx) to your equation, which will return the *absolute* value of the TimeSpan:

```
cc.DBAppointments.Where(c =>
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10).Subtract(c.StartDate).Duration() < oneMinute &&
    c.Approved == 1).ToList();
```